# How to open a new browser window and disabling back window

Tags: java, javascript, user-interface, jakarta-ee

Can you tell me how to open a new window(not a new tab) of browser on some event. While this new window remain in foreground & rest of browser in background. And user can not access the backside browser until foreground browser is closed. On closing front window user can again browse the back window.

Thanks

Comment: You can't. For modal dialogues use `alert()`, `confirm()` or `prompt()`, or you will have to use a in-window-solution as offered by many frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements don't sound to me like something you want to do in a new tab. New tabs (and new windows) should not necessarily shut down the parent window from activating. This will cause frustration for users when they find that they cannot access the other tabs they have open in that browser until they close down your window.

Additionally, in certain browsers, it is impossible to do this at all. The best way to guarantee the behaviour you are talking about would be disable all the elements on the page you don't want the user to interact with. Create an overlay element (just a big div) with a transparent grey colour (to make the elements behind it look disabled), and then place your "modal dialog" element in the foreground. That was you don't have to worry about pageloads or such.

The major advantage to doing it this way is that it will be compatible cross browser.

I've seen this done before using IFrames.

If you still need to know how do pop up a modal dialog, it can be done in IE using

> window.showModalDialog()

There is more information at [this link](http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodal.htm) about how to check for browser compatibility, but it won't solve the problem in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** You can't really, **if** you are referring to **browser** tabs/windows. You can set

```
<a href target="_blank" href="...">...</a>
```

Whether this will open a new *browser* tab or a new *browser* window will ultimately be a preference for the user in the browser, and not something which can be guaranteed through html.

Likewise, you cannot force how the user is supposed to interact with any **browser** back-buttons or **browser** window either.

---

**(2)**  **If** you are referring to **html** tabs/windows, you can use a [`modal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992142/html-modal-popup). A modal is typically a set of html code which you make appear on top of other html, usually using z-index and graying out the background.