# Showing div contents in modal popup

Tags: javascript

I have a situation in which the javascript function sets the `innerHTML` of `<div>` when mouse is clicked.I want the `<div>` to be loaded in to modal popup when mouse is clicked.
Here is the sample of javascript function

```
var map = 'show_map_codes...';
map.on('singleClick',function(evt)
{
     document.getElementById('pop').innerHTML = '<iframe seamless id="info_iframe" src="some_url"></iframe>';
});
```

This function is on external js file.

and i have the `<div>` i.e.

```
<div id='pop'></div>
```

which is on `aspx` page.

Then how i can show the `<div>` contents in modal popup ...?

Comment: I don't get on which element you put your event. `map.on` ? While `map` is a string. Sounds weird to me.

Comment: map is the dynamic variable in which the map object is initiated from open layer 3 js i.e GIS component which shows the specified map in the browser and when the mouse is clicked on map a `<div>` is to be loaded with some map information...@Elfayer

Answer (score 0):

[html Modal popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992142/html-modal-popup)

But since it's no longer 2010, you should probably use Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: It's true if he's already using bootstrap, but I wouldn't load bootstrap css and js and try to avoid naming conflict just for a modal

Comment: True, but judging by the question, he probably knows much more about computer science than webdev, so for future reference on any of his web development work, it was worth suggesting.